# Scrapy Inner Text with Spacing

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, scrapy, css-selectors

I'm trying to get the innertext of an element. However the element presents itself as such, with space in front of the inner tag and the text I want after the inner tag:

```html
<div>      <a href="#"></a> Hello!</div>
```

When I try and get the inner text using the following CSS selector:

```py
element.css('div::text').get()
```

It only returns the leading spaces        and not the text after the inner element. My question is, what do I need to do so that I can get `Hello!`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.get()` only returns a single result, since the div has multiple text node you should use `.getAll()`.

```
element.css('div::text').getAll()[1]
```